# Can I use data from API call in Angular ng-style directive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

I'm attempting to set the border color and box-shadow color around images pulled from an API based on other data from the API. Basically, I want these colors to be loaded dynamically. Through research I know that ng-style is the way to go and I'm 90% of the way there. I'm having problems using data returned from my API call in the CSS of ng-style.
See below:

relevant html:

```
<a href="{{item.link}}" target="_blank">
    <img src="{{item.images.standard_resolution.url}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" ng-style="homeColors" id="image">
</a>
```

relevant code from Angular controller:

```
Stadia.get($scope.id).success(function(response) {
    $scope.shadow = response.prim_hex;
    $scope.border = response.sec_hex;

    $scope.homeColors = {
        "border": "2px solid response.prim_hex",
        "box-shadow": "3px 3px 7px response.sec_hex",
        "margin": "6px",
        "padding": "0"
    }
```

I'm stumbling over how to get the API results (response.prim_hex and response.sec_hex) into my CSS object, homeColors, so they are loaded in my ng-style directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the variables' names being used as part of the string, rather than having them evaluated and appended.  Try the below:

```js
Stadia.get($scope.id).success(function(response) {
    $scope.shadow = response.prim_hex;
    $scope.border = response.sec_hex;

    $scope.homeColors = {
        "border": "2px solid " + $scope.shadow,
        "box-shadow": "3px 3px 7px " + $scope.border,
        "margin": "6px",
        "padding": "0"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about it?

```
$scope.shadow = response.prim_hex;
$scope.border = response.sec_hex;

$scope.homeColors = {
    "border": "2px solid " + $scope.shadow,
    "box-shadow": "3px 3px 7px " + $scope.border,
    "margin": "6px",
    "padding": "0"
}
```

Strictly, you should check the response value.

http://jsfiddle.net/xmj2q8Lj/6/